# eventbrite in react js getting started

Tags: reactjs, eventbrite

I really can't get anything out of this, I searched for hours I don't know where to start there is no a simple code example on this

Please can anyone give me some code example for a very very simple usage of eventbrite, What should I do first? I have registered and got my 4 keys

`API key **** Client secret **** Private token **** Public token ****`

how to integrate it, which npm plugin should I use for a very simple usage like searching events in any possible way

thanks in advance